Bash 5 - ghost function: removed but still available in Bash cache - exploit? bug?
GNU Bash version 5.1, WSL, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
$ bash -version
bash -version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


Edit .bashrc, create function foo:

foo() {
    echo 'GHOST'
}

save and exit

Source .bashrc:

. .bashrc

Now foo is a valid function:
type foo
foo is a function
foo ()
{
    echo 'GHOST'
}


Call foo(), it will print GHOST

Edit .bashrc, remove the function, source again

foo as a function still available for calling and type.

Restart a terminal window, it now stops existing.

Of course it also happens when you rename a function; and you keep calling the old version while repeating it pressing UP to use the one in history.


Bug? Feature? Exploit?

A full Ubuntu version number always helps. 22 is not a full version number.

@DavidDE I am using WSL; it is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

So that makes you behind in updates. A fully updated system is 22.04.5 Please edit the question and add the version info there.

Can you reproduce in latest version? But I would say it is there for some time...? I don't expect bash to suddenly stop caching and re-read .bashrc executing every function in between 2 minor versions

AFAIK sourcing a file does not (and has never) "unsourced" the previous version - if you want to remove foo from the current shell instance you can do so with the unset builtin i.e. unset -f foo

@steeldriver Ye I understand. It's just confusing at first for me but at second thought it's understandable.

@WesternGun perhaps it would help to think of sourcing files into a running shell as a cumulative process? You'd get the behavior you expect if you started a new interactive shell (provided you didn't export the function first).

Neither a bug nor a feature nor an exploit but simply a logical result of how things work. Sourcing .bashrc isn't anything special or magic. It doesn't re-create your shell setup or reset your session. It is no different to sourcing any other file, .bashrc is just the default name for the shell initialization file but even that can be changed by using bash --rcfile whatever or by setting BASH_ENV for non-interactive shells.
So when you source .bashrc, that doesn't remove anything, it simply adds to what you already have. It's like reading a book: after you ahve read one book, reading another book doesn't remove what you have learned in the first one, it simply adds to it. The only real difference is that in the case of bash, anything in the new sourced file that contradicts something in the old will overwrite the old. If, therefore, instead of deleting foo() you added a different foo() function, then this new one would overwrite the old one.
This isn't any form of caching, by the way. You just have a running process and tell it to import new stuff. The new stuff gets imported, anything that has the same name in the new stuff will be reset to the new values, anything not mentioned in the new stuff won't be touched.

OK so if someone disguises a malicious function with what we think it normally is and then remove the definition in the same session, it can do anything which others cannot know. Interesting.

@WesternGun what do you mean? Of course, if an attacker has already gained access to your system, they can do anything, yes, that's a bit of a tautology. You don't even need to edit any files to define a function: just run foo(){ echo "I am a function";} in a terminal and now you can run foo as a command. I mean, this is bog standard stuff on any system. Just like you can open a file in an editor and then delete the file from the disk, it's still there in your RAM. I don't see any exploit here, just a very normal behavior.

Ye you are right; at that point maybe we should be more concerned about other things. Haha.
